# Mail merge: How can I format indiviidual fields within "database" field

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

For a mail merge in Microsoft Word from data in Microsoft Excel, I have written a DATABASE field that successfully adds all of the fields I want and dynamically changes for each mail merge record ("many to one").

I have then tried to format the numbers within this DATABASE statement, but when I used `FORMAT()` the number did change to the format I wanted, however the header was replaced with `Expr1003`.

Is there a way to format the numbers within the DATABASE statement shown below but without losing the header titles?

Code without formatting:

```
{DATABASE \d"{FILENAME \p}/../data5.xlsx" \s "SELECT [Accountable Officer], [Cost Centre Group], [Description], [Annual Budget], [Outturn Forecast], [Outturn Forecast Variance] FROM [data$] WHERE [Accountable Officer] = {Quote 39}{MERGEFIELD Accountable_Officer}{Quote 39} ORDER BY [Cost Centre Group] "\l \b "16" \h}
```

If I amend Annual Budget with `FORMAT()` as below:

```
{DATABASE \d"{FILENAME \p}/../data5.xlsx" \s "SELECT [Accountable Officer], [Cost Centre Group], [Description], FORMAT([Annual Budget], '£#,##0;-£#,##0'), [Outturn Forecast], [Outturn Forecast Variance] FROM [data$] WHERE [Accountable Officer] = {Quote 39}{MERGEFIELD Accountable_Officer}{Quote 39} ORDER BY [Cost Centre Group] "\l \b "16" \h}
```

then the figures shown in the Annual Budget column are formatted correctly, but the header title then changes to `Expr1003` (or `Expr1004`, `Expr1006` etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the change in the field name is because the function is "hiding" the fied name. In this case, the Database field is creating an *expression* for the field name.

One way around this is to pre-format in the data source, in the case of Excel, by turning the cell content into text instead of a number.

The other way is to assign an *alias* as the field name using `AS`:

```
FORMAT([Annual Budget], '£#,##0;-£#,##0') AS Budget.
```

I *think* you should be able to use `AS [Annual Budget]`, but test this, first, to be sure the basic syntax works. My quick test in Access did *not* allow using the same field name as the alias, but my test in Word did allow it...

Comment: Thanks so much.  The alias works and allows the formatting.  You are correct that it won’t let me pick an alias that is the same as the field name.  I have had to use ‘Annual Budget’ instead of Annual Budget, but I don’t think it is too bad a trade off to have to choose between formatted figures or headers without odd single quote marks!